# Gitlab CI - should I keep a set of artifacts to be reused on a runner, for each job, without re-downloading artifacts on the pipeline?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, devops, artifacts

### On dev workstation

every time a git repo is cloned, a batch script must be run by the user on their workstation which bootstraps a bunch of things + **downloads a hefty 2GB zip** file before they can start development and compilation.

the download of the 2gb only needs to **happen once** in their workstation and a checksum process is triggered **each subsequent bootstrap** to verify if there's a change that's needed. if the checksum doesn't match, it means a new 2gb.zip is available and it downloads. If it matches, then the download process is skipped.

#### Gitlab CI Pipelines

We have pipelines that replicate the above steps, all until the end to ensure successful compilation.

For each job that is run (that is each commit pushed to the repo), **the 2gb artifact download process will always occur** - which makes sense, considering **each job is treated as a unique instance** to ensure the process is run from start to end successfully.

However, the 2gb artifact download takes time - around **10 minutes for each job run**. When developers need to quickly check in their code and also ensure a compilation process is complete in the pipeline, this large artifact chunk is a problem.

The artifact itself *does* change but seldomly.

What would be the best approach/practice to implement a "consistent" artifact that will exist on a runner so that it wouldn't need to redownload each time a job is started?

Is there such a feature on Gitlab CI?

Comment: What type of runner are you using?

Comment: The git lab ci runner that is provided

Answer (score 0):

The only way to overcome this and avoid the download entirely is with a self-hosted runner and having the 2gb file on the host. This cannot be done on gitlab.com (SaaS) shared runners.

For shell-based executors, simply put the file on the runner host.

For container-based executors (docker, kubernetes, etc), use a [volume mount](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#example-2-mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume):

```ini
[runners.docker]
  ...
  volumes = ["/pathto/zipdirectory:/path/to/bind/in/container:rw"]
```

Comment: We have our own live runners in premise, but this is something to consider when shift towards a cloud based infrastructure. I’ve never used containers but it looks interesting - does this mean I could have a container on my runner updating once a day?

Comment: Sure, yeah that would work @5zCI4b7XS6dg . You don't necessarily need to use containers, either. You can also self-host your own runners in the cloud, too.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own Dockerimage that has this zip built in.
The runner(s) will cache this once it is downloaded and subsequent runs won't pull the image again.

Use the `image` keyword to tell your job to use this image:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#image